# how to create a CLARANS cluster using distance matrix?

Tags: java, spring, matrix, cluster-analysis, smile

When I use CLARANS cluster with coordinates, then clustering is successful. When I try to write clustering with the distance matrix, then the points are grouped incorrectly. I use the `haifengl/smile` git repository, which has all the clusters I need. I attach a piece of code with a distance matrix and two .png files with clusters output.
[image]- with coords
[image] -with distance matrix

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lKYQep_yppJP3rhY_n-vZIvKJDbcrfpj - distance matrix file

```
Integer[] integers = new Integer[data.length - 1];
Distance<Integer> distance = (x, y) -> data[x][y];            
CLARANS clarans = new CLARANS(integers, distance, defaultK);
```

Comment: None of the links work for me. Can you please use the stack overflow image upload function instead? Because as is. I don't understand what your error is.

Comment: In the code snippet at the bottom, the `integers` array is all `null`... So this should cause a null pointer exception.